# Sign up instagram Using C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, httpwebrequest, instagram

so im working on an instagram tool. i need to Create an account with HttpWebRequest but somethings wrong with my code and it doesnt work here is the Code:

```
        username = "something";
        password = "something";
        mail = " something@mail.com";
        name = "something";
        string postData = "email=" + mail + "&password=" + password + "&enc_password=%23PWD_INSTAGRAM_BROWSER%3A6%3A1583227313%3AAXFQANTXAGE5jwEKNbpJbvot0SGTp%2Bq7a0ckELnuYQnQLIJa2Th6UwIqdknx%2FDa8R7q1%2F2Bt4scBUrh%2B1aFDKL0H%2Fut5cyi3w1sIEPa1keAuNcNj9nAXo1oFzUYMhCGVB7qerse5hQfMjTVjNa4%3D&username=" + username + "&first_name=" + name + "&seamless_login_enabled=1&tos_version=row&opt_into_one_tap=false";

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/emailsignup/");
        byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
        req.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
        req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();



        req.Method = "POST";
        req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36";
        req.Accept = "*/*";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.Referer = "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/emailsignup/";
        req.Headers["Accept-Language"] = "de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3";
        req.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip, deflate";
        req.Headers["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest";


        Stream dataStream = req.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
        dataStream.Flush();
        dataStream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse webResp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse(); //error in this line---> The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
        Stream datastream = webResp.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(datastream);
        string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: You should mention what kind of error is thrown.

Comment: @ManfredWippel i defined it as comment : The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.